# no arguments allowed for nullary method apply: ()play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable in object main

Tags: playframework

```
1@()
2
3@main("breakfast") { 
4<h1 class="text-center">Breakfast recipes</h1>
5
6<div class="alt-prg row">
7    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
```

Has anyone come across this error. Everything was working and now it wont compile

> main.scala

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<title>Online Shop - @title</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384- 
Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" 
rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")" 
rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
```

I have now added the main.scala file to see if there is an obvious error I am making.

Code from the breakfast.scala file

```
@()

@main("breakfast") {
<h1 class="text-center">Breakfast recipes</h1>

<div class="alt-prg row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <div class="rowImage"><img 
src="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/spotato.jpg")" alt="Alternate Text" /> 
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12  text-right">
    <h4>Sweet potato, Egg & Turkey Bacon</h4>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eum diceret vivendo ne, ei
        harum prompta tacimates mel. Te eum solet graeco maluisset,
        ius id malorum voluptatum. Mei vero suavitate ad, quo paulo 
        suavitate te.
        Eum id vidit deleniti appetere, modo stet dissentiet no usu. Ad his 
         clita debitis
        splendide, eleifend adversarium an eam, ea usu singulis omittantur
    </p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("recipes/Sweet 
        Potatoe,Egg _ Turkey Bacon.docx")">Download Recipe</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Can you see anything here that maybe causing an issue?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for getting back. Do you need to see the whole of that file?

Comment: Added now. thanks again

Comment: Hmm, your `main.scala.html` seems fine. Could you provide the full compilation error message with the name of file and line number where it occurs, for example: `[error]: example/app/views/index.scala.html:3: no arguments allowed for nullary method apply: ()play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable in object main`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. i still havent been able to correct it. is there anything more I can show from my side. Exact error says its in breakfast. html so i will add that also: no arguments allowed for nullary method apply: ()play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable in object main

In C:\Users\Kenne\JA\v1\play-java-seed\app\views\breakfast.scala.html:3

Comment: Yes, please show the source code of `breakfast.scala.html`

Comment: Strange, everything seems fine. Do you have a GitHub account where you could upload the whole project for us to have a look at?

Answer (score 2):

In general, the compilation error `no arguments allowed for nullary method apply` indicates we are passing an argument to `apply` method which does not accept any arguments. For example, the following

```
object A {
  def apply(): String = ""
}

A(3) // compiler sees this as A.apply(3)
```

gives a compilation error

```
no arguments allowed for nullary method apply: ()String in object A
```

In your case, the similar error

```
no arguments allowed for nullary method apply: ()play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable in object main
```

seems to indicate there exists a Twirl template `main.scala.html` with the following signature

```
@()

<html>
...
</html>
```

which Twirl translates into a `main` object similar to

```
object main extends BaseScalaTemplate {
  def apply(): play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable = {
    ...
  }
}
```

and is being called from some other place such as a controller or another Twirl template with an argument incorrectly passed to its `apply` method. For example, if we have`index.scala.html` calling `main` like so

```
@()

@main("breakfast")
```

then we get your compilation error

```
[error] example/app/views/index.scala.html:3: no arguments allowed for nullary method apply: ()play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable in object main
[error] @main("breakfast")
```